# design and implement social relationship issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts, visualization, data-visualization

I am using C# + VSTS 2010 + .NET 4.0 + ASP.NET + IIS 7 on Windows 7.

Currently I have some people relationships stored in a database. I am wondering how to implement the same visual effect shown in the demo linked to below?

Are there any ready-to-use C# libraries? Better if open source and free. :-)

> [SocialAction: Integrating Statistics and Visualization
>   for Social Network Analysis](http://www.cs.umd.edu/hcil/socialaction/)
>
> [The prefuse visualization toolkit](http://prefuse.org/)

Comment: Does anyone have any good ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The JIT](http://thejit.org/) (JavaScript InfoVis Toolkit) has a number of visualisations that are very similar to the ones demonstrated in those links.

It's free and opensource as well. It's not written in C# but client-side Javascript, all you need to do is supply the data as JSON.

Comment: @george2 - I just tried the link and it works. Try this: http://thejit.org/demos/